# C# delegate that returns itself

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Basically I want a delegate that may return itself. I have a very simple reduction of what I'd theoretically want below:

```
int i =0;
var x = () => 
{
    if (i > 10)
        return null;

    ++i;
    Debug.Log("keep going");
    return x;
};

var y = x;

while ((y = y()) != null) ;
```

The expected output of course is seeing "keep going" 10 times in the console. I simply want to know whether this is possible or not in this language (I am aware I can accomplish the same goal with a for loop). It is for example trivial to do in JavaScript using very similar code as above, but I can't get the compiler to cooperate with in C#. I think the failing is in not being able to properly describe a type for "x" `(Func<Func<Func...`, you kind of want something like a forward declaration).

Comment: have you tried this your self

Comment: Is there some real world case when this kind of code can be useful?

Comment: @JulieShannon Yes I have tried the exact code above and it complains about the "var" (perhaps I should mention I am running on Mono in Unity (.NET 2 compatibility), so perhaps the above code is perfectly legal in newer C# runtimes.

Comment: This concept isn't directly possible in C# for a simple reason: what would be the return type of the function `x`? It's possible only if the type is somehow "obscured".

You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679547/function-which-returns-itself

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Code that uses this technique is very common in functional programming. For example, you can have a parser function which returns the next step in parsing: `while (parse = parse(stream)) yield return wait_for_more_data;` The state of the parser is captured in the lambda closure, and thus makes it trivial to make the parser pause-able. Again though, I don't want to get into a discussion of alternative strategies, I simply want to know if C# can handle this.

Comment: @FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI see my answer bellow  please

Comment: @JulieShannon just "have you tried this yourself" or is there something else I'm missing (didn't see anything in the answers section, apologies if I just missed it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify my comment from earlier, C# uses static typing and "reified" generics. This means that the compiler keeps track of every parameterization of a generic type. The type `Func<Func<int>>` is distinct from the type `Func<Func<Func<int>>>`. C# does not support any kind of dynamic recursion of types, let alone infinite parametrization, and a naive construction of a type like `Func<Func<...` would involve infinite recursion that would manifest itself in having to keep track of an infinite number of types.

However, there are a few tricks that can make it work. They all involve somehow obscuring the return type of the function. The other solutions do this by returning a weakly-typed, late-bound `Delegate` object. However, there is also a statically typed solution. All you need do is define your own, non-generic `delegate` object.

```
    private delegate InfFunc InfFunc();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InfFunc f = null;
        int i = 0;
        f = () =>
            {
                if (i > 10) return null;
                i++;
                Debug.WriteLine("Keep going");
                return f;
            };
        var g = f;

        while ((g = g()) != null) ;
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Or you can do this, although your .NET version doesn't support the DLR:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<dynamic> f = null;
        int i = 0;
        f = () =>
            {
                if (i > 10) return null;
                i++;
                Debug.WriteLine("Keep going");
                return f;
            };
        var g = f;

        while ((g = g()) != null) ;
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thank you very much! RE: the second example, Func<object> seemed to work just fine (then doing = (Func<object>)(f())). But yes the first example was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you are hoping for, but this would do the trick:

```
        int i = 0;
        Func<Delegate> x = null;
        x = () =>
        {
            if (i > 10)
                return null;

            Debug.Log("keep going");
            ++i;
            return x;
        };
        Func<Delegate> y = x;
        while ((y = y() as Func<Delegate>) != null) ;
```

In order to solve the problem of having an infinite sequence of `Func<Func<...` you can use `Delegate` and then cast that to `Func<Delegate>` after invocation.

Comment: This seems to only loop once (using Mono that has .NET 2 compatibility in Unity -- apologies if this behaves differently in newer versions of C#)

Comment: Sorry, misread the output, this actually works fine. I selected the other similar answer just because it was earlier, but I have still given you an up vote.

Comment: That is fine, but you should know that `DynamicInvoke` introduces an additional overhead which is why I opted for the cast.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is to make the return type `Delegate`:

```
int i = 0;
Func<Delegate> f = null;
f = () =>
{
    if (i > 10)
        return null;

    ++i;
    Debug.WriteLine("keep going");

    return f;
};

Delegate y = f;

while ((y = (Delegate)y.DynamicInvoke()) != null)
{

}
```

Comment: This seems to only loop once (using Mono that has .NET 2 compatibility in Unity -- apologies if this behaves differently in newer versions of C#)

Comment: Sorry I was misreading the output, this actually works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on what you are trying to do but:

```
int i =0;
Func<Delegate> x = null;
x = () => 
{
    if (i > 10)
        return null;

    ++i;
    Console.WriteLine("keep going");
    return x;
};

var y = x;

while (y() != null) ;
```

Comment: y = y() is crucial because y() could potentially return a different function. for example, if (i > 10) return () => { Debug.Log("last"); return null }; Apologies for not making that clearer.